# Cannot install erdpy on macOS - failed building wheel for pynacl

Tags: macos, python-wheel, pynacl, multiversx, erdpy

I'm trying to install `erdpy` on a macOS by following the official guide, I successfully managed to download `erdpy-up` and when I run it, I receive the following error:

```
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "setup.py", line 161, in run
   raise Exception("ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH")
Exception: ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pynacl
Failed to build pynacl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pynacl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
CRITICAL:installer:Could not install erdpy.
```

Right before that, I see:

```
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for cffi, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pycryptodomex, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Building wheels for collected packages: pynacl
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517) ... error
```

Tried to install `libsodium` using brew but `erdpy` installation still failed.

Is there another way to install / build it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have `make` installed on my system. The log message is not very clear, but in the end I figured out how I can install erdpy on my Mac.
First I installed `libsodium`:

```
brew install libsodium
```

and then I installed `erdpy` using `pip3`:

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade --no-cache-dir erdpy
```

Then `erdpy -v` returns

```
erdpy 1.0.18
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the M1 processor, it won't install on Mac. You will have to remote connect to a linux system. VS code has the ability to do this, or you could use parallels and run a linux VM locally.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says you don't have the `make` utility installed.

Install it by executing

```
brew install make
```

in your terminal. Then retry the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also activate the virtualenv with `source ~/elrondsdk/erdpy-activate`and then use `pip3 install --upgrade --no-cache-dir erdpy`.